# Имя "l1" не существует в текущем контексте

Tags: c#, winforms

Здраствуйте, никак не могу понять как сделать так чтобы l1 был видимым для Form2

Код Form1.cs:

```
namespace _5;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Label l1 = new();
        l1.Location = new Point(20,10);
        l1.AutoSize = true;
        l1.Font = new Font("Arial",100);
        l1.Text = "Игра";
        Controls.Add(l1);
        Form2 F2 = new();
    }
}
```

Код Form2.cs:

```
namespace _5;

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        l1.Text = "Тест 2";
    }
}
```

Я буду рад любой помощи. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: у формы есть конструктор, добавьте в конструктор параметр - лейбл, и передавайте туда нужную переменную

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли мне)